# In Prestashop how to uninstall the theme?

Tags: php, themes, prestashop

I have created a theme in Prestashop and installed it, using these steps:

1. Login  as admin
2. Go to Module select Administration Tab in that Select Import/export a theme v1.4 by PrestaShop.
3. Follow the steps.

Now the problem is I've installed the theme but I can't uninstall the theme. Is there any way to uninstall the theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delete it in your FTP client. You should find the files in your /themes directory, just delete the entire folder for that theme.

Comment: Dear Mike Krazler, i have deleted the folder already. but still i have a doubt while i instal the theme i am installing a banner module also when i delete the folder that banner module still remains. what shall i do for it. thank you for your kind information.

Comment: Hi Diva,
The banner module you installed will likely be in the /modules folder of the root. You should be able to find it and delete it there.